# How magento 2 triggering purchase event in GTM

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I need to update the parameters names in the purchase event. But iam not able find from which file purchase event is triggering.

Any help can be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this steps

1.Identify the system or application where the purchase event occurs. Determine if it is a website, mobile app, or any other platform.

2.If it is a website, check the front-end code. Look for JavaScript files that handle user interactions and events. Common filenames include **app.js, main.js,**

3.If it is a mobile app, locate the relevant code files based on the platform

4.Search for keywords related to the purchase event, such as "purchase," "checkout," or "payment." Use your integrated development environment (IDE) or a text editor with search capabilities to search within the code files.

5.Once you find a relevant code section, examine it to determine if it is responsible for triggering the purchase event. Look for functions or methods that handle purchase-related actions, API calls, or event tracking.

6.Within the code section responsible for the purchase event, you should be able to find the parameter names being used. Update them as needed, ensuring consistency with any backend or analytics systems that rely on these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'don't know how you implemented GTM, but check your success page.
Look for layout files named checkout_onepage_success.xml Or search your code base for the trigger: `'event': 'purchase'`

Tom

Comment: HI @Tom van den Heuvel, we have out of the box configuration in magento 2 for GTM. Once we add GTM id, then its starts triggering events in GTM